# How to find which application had caused outgoing connection?

Tags: networking, server

Recently Amazon reported to me that one of my instance (running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is participating DoS attack. They have sent me auto-generated email that includes logs. It was a shock to me to see those logs because it shows some application on my instance connects to external IP addresses on UDP port 8763 and sends data. I never had directly or indirectly doing this kind of activity.

Log lines looks like:

```
1576787081.299481 54.x.x.140 → 104.x.85.138 UDP 8763 → 62058 Len=1052
1576787081.299588 54.x.x.140 → 104.x.85.138 UDP 8763 → 62058 Len=1052
1576787081.299631 54.x.x.140 → 104.x.85.138 UDP 8763 → 62058 Len=1052
1576787081.299842 54.x.x.140 → 104.x.85.138 UDP 8763 → 62058 Len=1052
1576787081.299913 54.x.x.140 → 104.x.85.138 UDP 8763 → 62058 Len=1052
```

Here 54.x.x.140 is IP address of my machine and 104.x.85.138 is where it had connected and sent data. All I like to know is there any way in Ubuntu which will tell me which application had connected to which external ports?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Essentially the same topic:  [Finding the PID of the process using a specific port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106561/85039)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `netstat` to check the network connections.

```
sudo netstat -tupln
```

You will see the `PID/Program name`, if the program name is fuzzy, you can filter the PID

```
ps aux | grep PID
```

to see which process use the port.

Further more, there is a program called `nethogs`, it group the process which shows the network activities per program.

```
sudo apt install nethogs
sudo nethogs
```